# Как беря данные с массива при null сделать условие что бы было другое значение?

Tags: php

```php
$address= $customerarray['address'];
```

Если адрес в массиве полученном имеет значение `null` 
пустует что делать?

как задать условие если `null` то пусть будет это значение `= Podval у маньяка`

Comment: ``if (значение == null) {значение = Podval у маньяка}``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$address= $customerarray['address'] ? $customerarray['address'] : 'Podval у маньяка';
```

Answer (score 2):

Если просто, то проверяем на существование переменной (isset) и на её пустоту (empty):

```php
if(isset($customerarray['address'])&&!empty($customerarray['address'])){
    $address= $customerarray['address'];
    // do something
}else{
    $address = "Podval у маньяка";
}
```

Comment: Функция empty делает так же проверку на isset

Comment: @Григорий всё верно. Спасибо.

Comment: @Григорий разница в том ещё, что isset не выбрасывает `Notice`, а `empty` выбрасывает.